# set image to each word present in a textview in Android

Tags: android, view, textview

i want to give a  bubble image to each word present in  A **Textview** 
so that the words are appear in a staggered view just similar to a design found while tagging friends on Facebook.But in my case i just need to have that design implemented in a TextView.
Thanks

Comment: So you want to animate the appearance of the text in the `TextView`?

Comment: well @Catalina i would like to animate the background of each text present in the Textview and not the text

Comment: Do you have an image that demonstrates what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes  i do have an image but my level on stack overflow isnt enough to upload a image